# How to remove x and y axis labels from a boxplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have been writing some code for a class, and I have got stuck in how to remove the x and y labels from the boxplot. I am planning to place it within a 1st graph, so they are redundant.

If anyone also knows how to add a line at 0 to my line graph, that would be amazing aswell!

Code:

```
#load data up 
library(readxl)
TempData <- read_excel("R Data/TempData.xlsx")
View(TempData)

#initiliase relevant packages #ggplot2 for creating data visulation and viridis to allow for colour gradients
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

#plot line graph
g1 <- ggplot(TempData, aes(x = Year, y = GAT, color = GAT)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5)  +
  geom_smooth(method=loess, se=TRUE, col = "black") +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "yellow" , high = "red", midpoint=median(TempData$GAT)) +
  labs(title = "Global Average Temperature", subtitle = "From 1850 to 2018") +
  xlab("Year") +  ylab ("Average Temperature") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 16)) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "italic", hjust = 0.5, size = 10, colour = "Orange")) +
  theme_light()

plot(g1)

#plot boxplot
g2 <- ggplot(TempData, aes(x="Year", y=TempData$GAT)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "red", outlier.fill = "red",outlier.shape = 21, outlier.size = 1)
labs(x=" ", y=" ") +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", size = 2.5, colour = "orange") +
  theme_light()

plot(g2)

#arrange two graphs to boxplot sits in top corner of line graph
g1 + annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(g2), xmin = 1840, xmax = 1930, ymin = 0.20, ymax = 0.88)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `theme` in the following way:

```
... + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

This will remove the x,y labels of the plot